# How to maintain the consistency of images in all the resolutions using Codename one?

Tags: codenameone

We are using images in my application but we have one issue with that i.e., the button was looking fine in 1280 x 800 resolution but in higher resolutions like 1920 x 1200 ,it was looking very small. Our requirement is to maintain consistency of images in all resolutions.

Comment: The above mentioned resolutions are of Android Tablets only

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Multi Images see [Understanding Images & Multi-Images](https://www.codenameone.com/manual/advanced-theming.html) in the developer guide. Notice that resolution doesn't matter, density matters as it is a better indicator for sizing elements.